# Constrain body in HTML to height necessary to hold content for small page

Tags: html, css, background-color, document-body

I have a webpage where the `background-color` for the `body` fills the browser window when the content is short. At times the content may be large and fill the browser window. Is there any way of controlling the `height` of the `body` to fit the content? I have tried setting the `height` of the `body` to `100%` and to `auto` but this does not help. Solutions that do not need `Javascript` are preferred. A minimal example is included:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-CA">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
        <title>Minimal Testcase for Body Height Sizing</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }
            body {
                background-color: #f7fad4;
                color: #262626;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Heading</h1>
        <p>Sample text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I set the `height` of the `body` to `auto`, the `height` is correctly reported by the Chrome development tools, but the `background-color` overflows and fills the browser window. So the question becomes, how to prevent overflow of the `background-color`.
`

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Always Helping A minimal test case has been added.

Answer (score 2):

Set HTML background-color to white.

```css
html{
    background-color: white;
}
```

CSS `body` `background` is designed to fill the whole `viewport` if `html` doesn't have any style applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the height of the html element aswell

```
html { 
height: 100%; 
}
body {
min-height: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: I did and it made no difference.